# Python regex not matching against pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a block that will take a file path from the user and check that the file path is a) actually a legitimate file path that opens a file, and b) that the first and last line of the .txt file fit this pattern:

-53.750 120.900 49.805

As it is now, the code that I'm using is not pattern-matching and is accepting any file.  Does anyone know which part of the code needs adjustment in order to get the desired filter?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

This is what I'm trying:

```
while True:
    try:
        fileInput = input("What is the file path?: ")
        openedInput = open(fileInput, 'r')
        inputList = []
        for line in openedInput:
            inputList.append(line)
        firstLine = inputList[0]
        lastLine = inputList[-1]
        print(firstLine)
        print(lastLine)

        if not re.match('.[0-9]+.[0-9]+\s.[0-9]+.[0-9]+\s[0-9]+.[0-9]+',firstLine) and re.match('.[0-9]+.[0-9]+\s.[0-9]+.[0-9]+\s[0-9]+.[0-9]+',lastLine):
            print("The data file must be in XYZ format, please submit a usable file: ")
            continue
        break
    except:
        print("That file path was not valid, try again")
```

Comment: `^[+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}\s[+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}\s[+-]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{3}$` would seem a better regex for what you are doing.

Comment: Check out the second last paragraphs on http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html "Use The Dot Sparingly"

Comment: That pattern turns out not to be correctly matching @Efferalgan

Comment: I tried to copy-paste my regex, and it appears that there is an invisible character hidden in the `\.[0-9]{3}$` part, which is not intended. Retype this part instead of copy-pasting it and the regex should match nicely, provided you do the other changes your code needs. The answer to your question does not lie within the regex (yours is correct albeit improvable), but in the way your are doing your tests, see my answer below.

Comment: Awesome, working well.. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of negation. What your code is currently doing is printing the error message only if the first line does not match and the last line does match.

It works fine with `if not (re.match(regex,firstLine) and re.match(regex,lastLine)):`, or `if not re.match(regex,firstLine) or not re.match(regex,lastLine):`

Comment: But I need both lines to match.  Infact even when I use this regex on just firstLine (without worrying about lastLine) it still doesn't match.  Any ideas what the issue is would be good

Answer (score -1):

You need to add **\** before **.** in you regular expression.
like this : [0-9]+**\.**[0-9]

Hope it helps, cheers.